# My default page in git page does not load when first loaded

Tags: reactjs, github

This is my code. The default page will not load when I first go to the git page. But will load the content after clicking on the home page nav link.
[source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBfQq.png)

this is my GitHub page link https://github.com/tekbhattarai/tekbhattarai/tree/master.
and this is my link to the git page https://tekbhattarai.github.io/tekbhattarai/

Comment: update your herf link of your header logo to `/home` not `/Home`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the package.json to include a homepage property. https://medium.com/mobile-web-dev/how-to-build-and-deploy-a-react-app-to-github-pages-in-less-than-5-minutes-d6c4ffd30f14

Answer (score 0):

Add homepage `property` to your `package.json` file like below:

```
"homepage": "http://{Github-username}.github.io/{Github-repo-name}"
```

follow this [unofficial deployment guide using `gh-pages` and `create-react-app`](https://dev.to/yuribenjamin/how-to-deploy-react-app-in-github-pages-2a1f)